# How do I completely remove and reinstall Samba on Debian?

Tags: debian, samba, uninstall, reinstall, aptitude

My Samba installation has become a mess, and now the services won't even start correctly anymore, for some reason.

Is there a way to completely remove Samba, as if it was never there, and then reinstall it so I can have a fresh setup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge samba
```

will remove the entire package, along with configuration files, which `apt-get remove samba` won't. After the purge, reinstall samba using

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

from `man apt-get`:

```
purge
    purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
    purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
```

Comment: Well it looks like that sort of worked, but now it seems to have hung on "Starting Samba daemons: nmbd smbd". I didn't see any errors before that, but to be fair it went by fairly quick, heh.

Comment: @Bob you may need a reboot

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick! I guess sometimes rebooting -does- work on *nixy stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @Bob Great it worked for you! Good luck with your fresh samba install! Haha! ;)

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu (17) I did

```
apt purge samba samba-common
```

followed by

```
apt install system-config-samba
```

which worked for me.

Comment: Debian 9.0 does not have a package called `system-config-samba`. But the hint of the package `samba-common` saved my day! So what I did was (as root) `apt purge samba samba-common`, `apt --purge autoremove` and finally `apt-get install samba`.

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04